# How to give multiple files an extension when they currently have none? (Windows 7)

Tags: cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

If you wish to change the extension on multiple files you simply change directory to the folder in question and simply use `ren`. But what if the file has no extension, i.e. someone deleted it.

Example:

If I wanted to change a folder full of .txt files to .xml I'd use

```
ren *.txt *.xml
```

But what if the .txt files did not have the .txt extension, so that letter.txt was simply letter?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command for renaming all files (including for those who do not have an extension)

```
ren *.* *.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

For files with out "." as window delete it if no extension is named do

```
ren * *.<extension>
```